# Test api laravel feature response 404 forever

Tags: laravel, phpunit

When doing any test is returning me **404**, and through the swagger url api/lojas/uuid he responds normally.

File:**LojasTest.php**

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class LojasTest extends TestCase

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
{


    public function testNenhumRecursoEncontradoParaOsCriteriosInformados(): void
        {
            $response = $this->get('/lojas/617752d2-175e-11ea-ae6f-0242ac120003');

            $response->assertStatus(200);
        }

}
```

File:**.ENV**

```
APP_DEBUG=true
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

**Error:**

> http://localhost/lojas/617752d2-175e-11ea-ae6f-0242ac120003 2019-12-06
>   17:43:23 GET 404 Symfony
>
> Expected status code 200 but received 404. Failed asserting that false
>   is true. 
>   /opt/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:151
>   /opt/project/tests/Feature/LojasTest.php:21

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved with the command.

```
php artisan serve
```